# How to Clear WPF IDataErrorInfo Validation Errors

Tags: wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo

I am using IDataErrorInfo inherited business objects for validation.

```
public string UserId { get; set; }

public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;

            if (columnName == "UserId")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserId))
                    result = "Please enter User Id";
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to clear all the validation errors when I click a button on the menu - like - LogOut.

Window is making the Login panel visible but the previous panel's validation error marks are still appearing in the current login panel.

I tried all the options to assign NULL datacontext, fresh entity object...but no luck

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `IDataErrorInfo` interface is an error-first type approach. This means that you will see the error(s) until they are cleared. You can see that there is no setter on the indexer.

The original `IDataErrorInfo` interface is not overly useful by itself as it only deals with one error at a time. I added the following field into my `BaseDataType` class:

```
protected ObservableCollection<string> errors = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

In my actual data classes, I have the following property:

```
public override ObservableCollection<string> Errors
{
    get
    {
        errors = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        errors.AddUniqueIfNotEmpty(this["Property1"]);
        errors.AddUniqueIfNotEmpty(this["Property2"]);
        errors.AddUniqueIfNotEmpty(this["PropertyN"]);
        return errors;
    }
}
```

The `AddUniqueIfNotEmpty` method is an extension method which I believe is self-explanatory. This property calls the indexer any number of times and compiles all of the results into a `ObservableCollection<string>` collection ready to be displayed in the UI. You'll need to call the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event with the name `Errors` when `Property1`, `Property2` and `PropertyN` are updated to make this work.

You could do something like this, but add a setter for you to pass in an empty collection or string when you want to clear the errors.